# Block passed to find_or_create_by doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `User` with attributes `status` and `email`. `status` can be `:active`, `:pending` or `:invited` (*default* status is `:active`). I want to check if a user with the passed email exists already and to retrieve it if it does, otherwise I'd like to create a new one with `status = :invited`. To do that I use:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by!(email: params[:email]) do |u|
  u.status = :invited
end
```

as in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by.

The problem is when **created** in that way, the new user has again `status = :active`

```
> user = User.find_or_create_by!(email: 'example@example.com') do |u|
>   u.status = :invited
> end

> user.status 
=> "active"
```

Does anybody know why it happens like that?

Comment: Status active will return only for existing user. For a new record, the status will be invited. Have you confirmed it is active while creation ?

Comment: Status is "active" even for newly created users.

Comment: Could you tell how are you setting the default status? just checking it won't override after creating!

Comment: @Zozo: It can be overridden if you are doing it via some callback. Explain ?

Comment: @Nimir I set the default value when I created the table `users`.

Comment: @Zozo: Please paste the code of migration.

Comment: @Nimir create_table :users do |t|  t.string :email  t.string :status, default: 1  end  (1 maps to "active", sorry for the bad formatting)

Comment: If you did using a db default value then there is no way this is happening. @Shadwell answer is correct, you must have tried finding_or_creating an existed user and hence your block is not needed!

Comment: @AmanGarg Yes, I use enum

Comment: @Nimir I've tried at least 10 times with different emails. Even in the console it's happening that way. However, when I do `user.status = :invited` outside the block, it's working fine.

Comment: @zozo Paste user.rb code which you are using for enum.

Comment: @AmanGarg enum status: { active: 1, invited: 2, pending: 3 }

Comment: @zozo I have got the problem, explaining in answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you linked:

> The block will only be executed if the client is being created. The second time we run this code, the block will be ignored.

The status will only be set to `:invited` when a user is created for the first time. If it found a user with that email already then it will just return that user with its status set to what it already was ('`active`' I presume).

If the status is being set to active then it suggest that a user already exists with that email.

Comment: Yes, I mean the case when the user is created, i.e. there isn't an existing user with that email.

Comment: I know you said *created* but how are you telling that it was created rather than found? I'm questioning whether it did actually create it. Does that sub-block actually get executed? Does the `created_at` date on the user show that it is created now that instant? Are you *certain* it created it because of the `find_and_create_by!`? (And how are you certain?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are treating status field as **enum**, then you should store it as an **integer**. 
The problem here is that the datatype of status field is string.

```
user = User.find_or_create_by!(email: 'example@example.com') do |u|
  u.status = :invited
end
```

Due to non conventional mapping with the status field, value is not properly parsed by enum.

It will work fine after changing status column datatype to integer which is basic convention for enum in rails.

Comment: Actually, I posted in the comment above an old migration. Afterwards, the field `role` was changed to Integer. ( sorry, for misleading you )

Comment: However, why does it work when executed outside the block?

Comment: I am not able to replicate this problem in this way. Its working fine when tested with a POC. Please check all your code again or try in a POC.

Comment: Sorry, but what is POC?

Comment: A short form for Proof of concept. Like a small application or program for checking some concept individually.